# Pushing new Git branches and subsequently merging them on the origin

Tags: git, merge, branch, gitlab

I am relatively new to Git and am trying to establish a certain workflow/procedure, and not quite sure how to implement it. FWIW I'm using Gitlab, although I don't think that should matter.

Currently a repo has only the master/mainline and no other branches.

I would like to:

1. Clone this project locally
2. Create a new branch, locally
3. Commit and push that branch remotely to the Gitlab server (but not merge it with master)
4. At a later time, initiate a merge request to merge the remote branch with the remote master

Obviously, for #1 we have `git clone http://path-to-my-gitlab-repo`. For #2 (creating the branch locally) I *believe* I want `git branch mybranchname`. However I am not sure how to then actually push the branch to the remote Gitlab server (since it doesn't exist there at all), nor how to - at some later time - initiate the merge request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**

> Clone this project locally

Make sure you want to use the http protocol for what you are doing. Depending on your team's security strategy, you may want to use SSH. The GitLab UI has buttons to toggle between the two so you can copy-paste the clone statement.

**Step 2:**

> Create a new branch, locally

You can use the checkout command to create and switch to a new local branch:

```
git checkout -b mybranchname
```

This is the same as (use whichever you prefer):

```
git branch mybranchname
git checkout mybranchname
```

**Step 3:**

> Commit and push that branch remotely to the Gitlab server (but not
>   merge it with master)

You can push to the server using this command:

```
git push origin mybranchname
```

**Step 4:**

> At a later time, initiate a merge request to merge the remote branch
>   with the remote master

Once you have pushed the remote branch you can initiate the merge request via the GitLab UI.

Find the new remote branch that you created and look for the green "Create Merge Request" button.

The later-half of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raXvuwet78M) has a very good short tutorial for creating and managing a merge-request.

Answer (score 1):

### Pushing a local branch to a remote repository

You can push a local branch to a remote repository named `origin` by saying:

```
git checkout <branchname>
git push origin <branchname>
```

If `<branchname>` *doesn't exist* in the remote repository, it will be created as part of the `push` operation.

Since you'll probably be pushing new commits from this branch, it's a good idea to establish a relationship between your local branch and the [remote tracking branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_remote_tracking_branch) by adding the `--set-upstream` (or `-u`) option:

```
git push --set-upstream origin <branchname>
```

Going forward, this will allow you to push new commits to the remote branch by simply saying:

```
git push
```

### Creating a Merge Request with GitLab

You can than create the *merge request* using the GitLab web UI as described in [the documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/gitlab_flow.html#mergepull-requests-with-gitlab-flow).